# How is Keras Dropout actually perfomed?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dropout

I was trying to understand how `K.layers.Dropout` might be implemented, since in the literature it's always referred as a random independent sampling of 0/1 masks for each element.

Given that the literature it's pretty clear to me, I switched to coding it, and I stumbled upon an issue: since TF uses Graphs, we don't know the sample size, in particular:

```
def class CustomLayer(K.keras.Layer)
  def call(inputs):
    tf.print(inputs.shape)
```

will indeed print (supposing the eager evaluation is turned off) `None` as first dimension

Having said that, how is TF able to sample an independent mask for each sample in each minibatch?

At the moment my best guess is that they are using something like `tf.vectorized_map` to get the performance they are getting with a random mask for each element in the minibatch

Comment: here is the code that gets the shape of the noise array used for dropout: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/07e13740fd181fc3ddec7d9a594d8a08666645f6/keras/layers/regularization/dropout.py#L90-L101

Comment: @jakub yes, even with my IDE I can see the source, but I'm asking for an explanation, that code return `None` when we use Graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I traced the code for `tf.keras.layers.Dropout.call` in an effort to answer the following question (tensorflow 2.9):

> how is TF able to sample an independent mask for each sample in each minibatch?

In summary, a random uniform distribution is sampled from [0, 1) with *the same shape as the input* (including batch dimension). This allows the method to use an independent mask for each sample. The noise array is then made into a boolean mask based on the dropout rate. This is all assuming that one keeps `noise_shape=None` when instantiating the `Dropout` layer.

I have copied [the relevant lines](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d8ce9f9c301d021a69953134185ab728c1c248d3/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L5695-L5700) below.

```
noise_shape = _get_noise_shape(x, noise_shape)
# Sample a uniform distribution on [0.0, 1.0) and select values larger
# than or equal to `rate`.
random_tensor = uniform_sampler(shape=noise_shape, dtype=x_dtype)
keep_mask = random_tensor >= rate
ret = gen_math_ops.mul(ret, gen_math_ops.cast(keep_mask, x_dtype))
```

In the case that `noise_shape=None` in the `Dropout` layer, `_get_noise_shape` [will return the shape of the input `x`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d8ce9f9c301d021a69953134185ab728c1c248d3/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L5310-L5311). This is done with the graph-compatible method [`tf.shape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape), which evaluates the shape of the tensor at runtime.

---

Here is an overview of the process for the TensorFlow / Keras v2 API.

1. Instantiate [`tf.keras.layers.Dropout` layer](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/07e13740fd181fc3ddec7d9a594d8a08666645f6/keras/layers/regularization/dropout.py#L26) (with `noise_shape=None`).
2. Call the `Dropout.call` instance method on an input `x`.
3. Call `self._random_generator.dropout`, which calls [`BaseRandomLayer._random_generator.dropout`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/07e13740fd181fc3ddec7d9a594d8a08666645f6/keras/backend.py#L1934-L1941), which calls [`tf.nn.experimental.stateless_dropout`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d8ce9f9c301d021a69953134185ab728c1c248d3/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L5485)

   - There is conditional logic in `BaseRandomLayer._random_generator.dropout`: v2 api will use `stateless_dropout` and v1 api will use `tf.nn.dropout`.
4. Call [private method `_dropout`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d8ce9f9c301d021a69953134185ab728c1c248d3/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L5627), which then constructs the noise array to be the same shape as the input tensor `x`.
5. [Apply the noise array to the input](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d8ce9f9c301d021a69953134185ab728c1c248d3/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L5700), and return the result.

Comment: thanks for the time you have taken to answer my question... just a clarification, `tf.size` includes also the batch size?  I tried before asking this question and it was not working, I'll check again... in case, thank you sooooo much

Comment: `tf.shape` will return the full shape, including the batch dimension. (btw i assume this was a mistake, but in your comment you reference `tf.size`. that will return the number of elements in the tensor, which is effectively the product of the shape array).

Comment: Actually no, because in my implementation i was using `tf.random.categorical` that asks for a 0-D array, that is the product, but obviously once either size or shape works, you can infer the other one... but yes, this solves my doubt, I'm just dumb because I was doing `print(inputs.shape)` that obviously returns the None

Comment: Ah, I see! I'm glad this helped. And good luck with the rest of your implementation.